# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 120

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

I am using the following url for fetching values from server.

```
http://yyy.com/2013-01-01/search?q=t*&q.options={"defaultOperator":"and","fields":["name"]}&fq=(and directorytype:'directory1')
```

I am gettting the following error when running the app

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 201

The error is pointing to the following line of code

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
```

Can anybody help

Comment: If you want to send json data shouldn't you use `HttpPost`?

Comment: please post relevant code

Comment: Have you checked the `Illegal character in query at index 201`? As your posted url is much to short we can't know. What about the comment from  @SudhirSingh?

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your parameters values.
You can't have spaces,*,(,) and many more characters in your url, for example space should be %20 instead.
Use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(String s, String encoding)` to encode them.